# Memory management for returned NSString variables

Tags: iphone, memory, nsstring

I have a variable set for my AppDelegate which stores the current URL that has been clicked on in a UIWebView. This variable is set in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest function, as below:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString *val = [request.URL absoluteString];

    currentURL = val;
    return YES;
}
```

The problem is that later in the application, accessing currentURL causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error because the NSString has been destroyed. However, if I add a 'retain' to when the variable is being assigned, like:

```
NSString *val = [[request.URL absoluteString] retain];
```

Then this means that every time a page is viewed, a new string is retained which is never released, causing a memory leak. How can I later release all of these retained strings?

I am storing this value so that the page reloads when there is a problem loading the page.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [ausWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentURL]]]
}
```

I'll bet it's something simple.

Comment: How did you define the property in the header file?

Comment: In the @interface, I did:
`NSString *currentURL`
Then added the property:
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *currentURL;`
And then synthesized it in the .m file:
`@synthesize currentURL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that currentURL retained property you should do:

```
NSString *val = [request.URL absoluteString];
[currentURL release];
currentURL = [val retain];
```

and in your dealloc

```
[currentURL release];
```

or when you synthesized you retained property you only have to do in your shouldStartLoadWithRequest (still need to dealloc of course):

```
self.currentURL = [request.URL absoluteString];
```

Comment: Ahhh.... yes, that works. I didn't realise that using `self.currentURL = ` is different to just `currentURL = `

Thanks so much!! =:)

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{

        NSString *val = [request.URL absoluteString];
        if(currentURL)
        {
            [currentURL release];
            currentURL = nil;
        }
        currentURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:val];
        return YES;
}
```